# Form POST calls GET Action in ASP.NET Core controller using Active Directory Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory

Form that POSTs to controller actions are converted to GET requests by the time the controller is called. The following is what was rendered in the browser (F12) to verify method="post".

```
<form action="/ebw/AcceptTermsAndConditions" method="post">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        ....
</form>
```

Then for some reason the redirect to the company Azure AD authentication kicks off even though this specific controller does not have [Authorize] attribute anywhere.

[image]

Then after the post, this [HttpGet] method is called instead of [HttpPost] method. (I can understand why now the GET is getting called as the browser is redirecting to the URL in the image above before returning to my website controller - but not sure how to control this behavior)

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AcceptTermsAndConditions(string FailRedirectUrl)
```

The following code never is executed

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AcceptTermsAndConditions(IFormCollection collection)
    {
```

In addition if I inspect the Request object, the request Method is "GET" instead of POST.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: what happens if you create a sample controller and httppost action method in that and try to call that action? Does that work without issues?

Comment: Have you enabled [global filters](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute/)which allows you to add the AuthorizeAttribute filter to the global.asax file to protect every action method of every controller.

Comment: Muqeet, I did create a sample controller and httppost action method via a Scaffold New Item - just in case there was something I was missing, and it still has the same problem. The Create and Edit will not post and always call the GET action for these. I only have this problem with using Active Directory authentication

Comment: Nan Yu, I don't know of using global.asax in MVC Core. I am using the [Authorize] and [AllowAnonymous] where applicable and at the "class" level.

Comment: Muqeet, I created a whole new project with Active Directory authentication and scaffolded new Controller + View + EntityFramework and it worked. I found that our custom Middelware some how caused this problem

Comment: Sorry for not notice you are using .new core , And if you find the root cause, you could write the answer which may help others :)

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I had included a middleware class that I just remarked out yesterday and the problem went and didn't report back because of a crunch in my schedule.

However, this code caused the problem was really made for API services, and it's now very understandable:

```
//This middleware offers source authentication prior to routing to page controllers if the call is to an API controller
app.UseMiddleware<SourceAuthentication>();
```

The Invoke() method of the class looks for GET or POST and if POST looks up the credentials in the Authorize header and logs it otherwise replies with StatusCode 401

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, AspNetUsersContext usersContext, SourceLogContext sourceContext)
{
   string authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
   if (context.Request.Method.ToString() == "GET")
   {
       // Log the GET access here, etc. and continue
   …. 
       await _next.Invoke(context);
       return;
    }

    if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic"))
    {
        //Extract credentials
        string encodedUsernamePassword = authHeader.Substring("Basic ".Length).Trim();
        var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
        string usernamePassword = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedUsernamePassword));

        int seperatorIndex = usernamePassword.IndexOf(':');

        var username = usernamePassword.Substring(0, seperatorIndex);
        var password = usernamePassword.Substring(seperatorIndex + 1);

        var source = usersContext.AspNetUsers.SingleOrDefault(r => r.UserName == username && r.PasswordHash == password);

        if (source != null)
        {
            // If found source creds, then log and continue…………
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //Unauthorized
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // This Caused the Error
        // no authorization header
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return;
    }
}
```

The very last line caused the problem!
So during the POST the response was an immediate 401 without reaching the MVC part of the request pipeline.
This middleware works great for REST API calls, but is detrimental to MVC view-controller activities.